# Automatically grow static table view cell height to fit label content height

Tags: swift, uitableview

Here a low quality mockup of my cell layout:

[image: mockup]

The initial height of the static cell (set in storyboard) is 80. Inside this cell are two views. The bottom view has a fix height of 40. The top view has layout constraints to align to top margin and to vertically align to the bottom view.

Inside the top view is a label (blue color) and a button (yellow color)

The label also has the constraints to align to the top of the view and to align to the bottom of the view. The idea behind that layout and constraints is that if I increase the height of the cell to 100 for example, the bottom view height stays 40 and the top view and label height is getting expanded to a height of 60.

My label has linebreak word wrapping and number of lines set to 0. What I now want is to automatically resize the cell so that the complete content of the label is getting shown when there are more than one lines. How exactly can I do that?

**I tried:**

```
self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 80.0;
```

This is not working. The cell height always stays 80 independend from the amount of lines in the `UILabel`.

I also tried:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
}
```

With the same result as my first approach.

The more complex way I tried was the following:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    let heightLabel = self.heightForView(text: self.lblTitle.text!, font: UIFont(name: "Helvetica Neue", size: 18)!, width: self.lblTime.width);
    let heightView = (heightLabel + (80.0 / 2));

    print("title label height \(heightLabel)");
    print("title view height \(heightView)");

    if (heightView > 80.0) {
        return heightView;
    }

    return 80.0;
}

func heightForView(text: String, font: UIFont, width: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
    let label: UILabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude));
    label.numberOfLines = 0;
    label.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping;
    label.font = font;
    label.text = text;
    label.sizeToFit();

    return label.frame.height;
}
```

output:

```
title label height 42.5
title view height 82.5
```

But this also does not seem to work since the other lines are not showing up, only the first line of the label.

How can I get this working?

**EDIT**

I guess the approach with calculating the label height will work when I know the width of the label. But how should I know it?

Comment: Instead of `self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 80.0;` set `estimatedRowHeight` to 120.0;.
`estimatedRowHeight` will not allow the tableView row to go beyond 80 if you set 80. if you need it to expand more than 80, you have to set it as 120.
For more https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableview/1614925-estimatedrowheight

Comment: and if it should be bigger than 120? the height can be dynamically every height (dependend on the amount of lines of the label).

Comment: I just gave you an approx height. you have to set the maximum value according to the messages you are showing.

Comment: So this is an approach which definitely wont work since I have multiple labels which can all have different heights.

Comment: You mean in a single cell you have multiple labels?

Comment: The cells will adapt to different sizes automatically if you set estimated row height.

Comment: I mean that I have several static cells with different content. Some of them are having labels with different text contents. So they all can have different heights. If I set the approx height to 120 to get the label of static cell A growing correctly it does not mean that it works for another static cell.

Comment: I think you are confused. You don't need to calculate height for each rows. If you set `estimatedRowHeight`. Follow this https://www.raywenderlich.com/129059/self-sizing-table-view-cells

Comment: ok, but there is one problem left. If I do as you recommended me to do nothing is happening. The cell heights arent growing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From personal experience getting UITableCells to grow correctly is one of the most annoying things in iOS. The biggest gotcha is normally the constraints. If they are not perfect than the cell won't grow.

The key is to be able to draw a straight line from the top of the cell content view to the bottom of the content view. so from your example constants should look something like the following.

```
topView.top == contentView.top
label.top == topView.top
label.bottom == topView.bottom
topView.bottom == bottomView.top
bottomView.height == 40
bottomView.bottom == contentView.bottom
```

Without having that straight line the layout can't determine the correct height for the label to display all of the content.

So a rather simple version of what you are looking for in a new sample project:

```
class ViewController: UITableViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 80.0

        label.text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }
}
```

With the same layout:
[Layout of Table Cell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AYocF.png)

Results in the following display in the simulator.
[Result Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/etOcM.png)

Comment: Thx. But I already got the correct constraints. If I increase the cell height in the storyboard the layout behaviour is working correctly as I expect it to be. The only problem is getting the correct height for the cell.

Comment: The other thing to try is to override the function heightForRowAtIndexPath. Not sure why but for static cells it seems necessary.

Comment: override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}

Comment: Just updated answer. With additional info from a working sample. I will get the sample project on GitHub in a minute.

Comment: Hi, this seems to work but it also squishes all of my other cells. Is it possible to provide a minimum height?

Comment: Sample project if you want to see. https://github.com/rjhodge/TestTable for minimum height add a height constraint to the topView and set it as >= to what you want the min height to be,

Comment: @BinaryPlatypus          it is not necessary to call in viewDidLoad `self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension` because you are returning in `heightForRowAt` the `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` property